# Read local xls/xlsx file in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xls, xlsx

Can we read large local xls/xlsx file in angularjs/Javascript without using any liabrary, if not then which is most suitable library?

Answer (score 3):

use this code to read

```
 <script>
/* set up XMLHttpRequest */
var url = "test.xlsx";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function(e) {
  var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

  /* convert data to binary string */
  var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
  var arr = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
  var bstr = arr.join("");

  /* Call XLSX */
  var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});

  /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
  var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  /* Get worksheet */
  var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
  console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true}));
}

oReq.send();
    </script>
```

Comment: Where are you getting the XLSX object from? Is this a library? If so could you please update your post to show what it is, and where you got it from? Also it would be helpful to see how you included it in this code block. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx is better liabrary at this time. But in my way files xlsx - are not reading, and files older then 2003 version of Excel also has trouble. But in official docs write then it is supported. But maybe just I have this trouble.
I also use this feature for get json from excel:

```js
var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(worksheet);
```