# Read Xlsx and csv file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, csv, readfile

I need to read each line of xlsx and csv file in angularjs and get its data in json format.

Currently I am using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) to get that file like this.

```
$scope.LatLongUploader = new FileUploader({
    //url: "/Map/UploadDamageRatioFile",
    queueLimit: 1,
    removeAfterUpload: true
});

$scope.locationUpload = function () {

        console.log( $scope.LatLongUploader)
        console.log( $scope.LatLongUploader.queue[0].file)
}
```

and in my html:

```
      <div ng-show="true" style="margin-top:4px">
      <input style=" width:212px; float:left" type="file" nv-file-select uploader="LatLongUploader" accept=".xlsx" class="AddLocationUpload" />
      <button ng-click="locationUpload()" ng-disabled=""  id="uploadlatlongfile" title="Upload Latitude Longitude File"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></button></div>
```

Now I am unable to proceed with this file like object.i found several ways to read this file like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353676/how-to-read-csv-file-content-in-angular-js)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465930/read-local-xls-xlsx-file-in-javascript).But these are not working.I found some github projects like [this_1](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)  and [this_1](https://github.com/bahaaldine/angular-csv-import).

I want help in what is best practice to do so?

Should I do this file reading in my server side code and send data to client side?

Which third party app/widget is good for this purpose?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I managed to get the file like this...

```
$scope.getLatLonGFile = function () {
        var FileUpload = document.getElementsByClassName('AddLocationUpload');
        $scope.file = FileUpload[0].files[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < FileUpload.length; i++) {
            FileUpload[i] = function () {
                $scope.file = this.files[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can easily read the file by `$scope.file`  and get data according to the need.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you consider to push data in $scope.file than replacing everytime?  

// like:  $scope.file.push(this.files[0])

Comment: but why should i keep those data in scope which i don't need...i think it depends on what scnerio do u have..